# Process causing significant battery drain during sleep (MBP 14)

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, bluetooth, sleep-wake

This process `com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetric` is causing ~20 percent battery drain while my computer is put on sleep overnight

every 15 minutes this is sending a wake request and I can see in my CPU usage history the same 15 minutes the CPU spikes.  I have disabled bluetooth wake from sleep setting and I am still getting the drain.

Does anyone have any ideas what that process is doing?  Thanks!

Comment: What method are you using to determine that this is the responsible process? (And are you copy-pasting this or typing by hand? There is an extra `o` in `bluetooth`.)

Comment: Copied the process
`2021-12-05 06:50:09 -0600 Wake Requests        [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=921 wakeAt=2021-12-05 07:05:29 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-05 08:50:08 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=295975 wakeAt=2021-12-08 17:03:03] `

Comment: ` pmset -g log | grep "Wake Requests"`